# Averaging a time series of amounts by week

Tags: date-and-time, time-series

I have a set of data with a list of dates (all Sundays in this case) and associated amounts. Most of these are every week, but some correspond to multiple weeks added together. I would like to average over those items that contain multiple weeks, to have just single weeks.

```
data = {{"18/03/2018", 323.4}, {"25/03/2018", 339.55}, {"01/04/2018", 201.45}, {"15/04/2018", 733.17}, {"29/04/2018", 691.44}, {"06/05/2018", 383.16}, {"13/05/2018", 386.2}, {"20/05/2018", 218.33}, {"27/05/2018", 382.7}, {"10/06/2018", 735.43}, {"17/06/2018", 232.15}, {"24/06/2018", 430.2}, {"01/07/2018", 298.5}, {"08/07/2018", 338.5}, {"15/07/2018", 264.05}, {"29/07/2018", 625.44}, {"05/08/2018", 353.01}, {"26/08/2018", 274.19}, {"02/09/2018", 368.25}}

data2 = {DateObject[{#[[1]], {"Day", "Month", "Year"}}], #[[2]]} & /@ data
```

You can see how multiple weeks are combined, resulting in a higher data point:

```
DateListPlot[data2, Joined -> False]
```

[image]

I know I could do this manually by working out the difference between each pair of data points, but as I'm so unfamiliar with how to use date/time objects I suspect there is a better way. My goal is to work on the weekly averages (to predict the overall trend).

Answers that don't require the data to be regular days each week (i.e. not always a multiple of 7 days between them) would be nice to see too.

Comment: tried [TimeSeriesAggregate](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TimeSeriesAggregate.html)?

Comment: @kglr, i couldn't see any obvious way to do it with that.

Comment: KraZug, i thought your data contained multiple observations for some weeks. With your data (some observations are aggregates of several weeks ) you need an initial processing to resample. I wil post an answer if i can come up with a clean way to combine the two steps.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that this could be solved with `TimeSeriesAggregate` as kglr has pointed out, but here is a different solution:

```
{dates, values} = Transpose@data2;

nWeeks = Floor@Prepend[1]@BlockMap[
     QuantityMagnitude@DateDifference[#[[1]], #[[2]], "Week"] &,
     dates, 2, 1
     ];

pos = Floor /@ Accumulate[nWeeks];
nWeeks = Normal@SparseArray[pos -> nWeeks];
values = Normal@SparseArray[pos -> values];

forwardFill[list_] := FoldList[If[#2 == 0, #, #2] &, list]
backFill[list_] := Reverse@forwardFill[Reverse@list]

dates = Append[Last[dates]]@DateRange[First[dates], Last[dates], "Week"];
values = backFill[values]/backFill[nWeeks];

DateListPlot[Transpose@{dates, values}, Joined -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This gives me one more element in dates than values, and hence the `Transpose` fails.

Comment: @KraZug I just tried it again and it works. Try to restart your kernel and see if that helps. If that doesn't help, please tell me what version of Mathematica you're on. I'm on 11.3.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `TimeSeriesResample` to insert `0`s at skipped weeks, `Split` to re-group the data, and take averages in each group:

```
data2B = Join @@ (Thread[{#, Mean@#2} & @@ Transpose[#]] & /@ 
  Split[TimeSeriesResample[data2, "Week", ResamplingMethod->{"Constant", 0}], #[[2]]==0 &]);

mesh = DateRange[#, DatePlus[#2, {1, "Week"}], "Week"] & @@ DateBounds[data2[[All, 1]]];
gridlines = Join[data2[[All, 1]], Thread[{Complement[mesh, data2[[All, 1]]], Red}]];

DateListPlot[{data2, data2B}, GridLines -> {gridlines, None}, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

**Update:** Alternatively, you can use `ResamplingMethod -> None` and use `SequenceReplace` to replace sequences of `Missing[]` followed by a value with the value divided by the length of the sequence:

```
data2C = Transpose[MapAt[SequenceReplace[
     s : {__Missing, c_} :> Sequence @@ ConstantArray[c/Length[s], Length[s]]], 
    Transpose[Prepend[Rest[TimeSeriesResample[data2, "Week", ResamplingMethod -> None]], 
      First[data2]]], {2}]];
data2C == data2B
```

> True